# Render any child component with props from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a need to be able to call a container component and render any of a list of child components from a string.

The children will all look something like this:

```
<ChildOne store={store} name="child-one" foo="bar" />
<ChildTwo store={store} name="child-two" foo="bar" />
<ChildThree store={store} name="child-three" foo="bar" />
```

As you can see, all of the props are the same apart from the Component Name itself and the `name` prop.

The container should be called like this, ideally:

`<Container child='child-one' />`

but I'd also be fine with any other implementation that yielded the same result. I've worked out how to do it a long way around but it involves repeating a lot of code and putting a `switch` in my container, so I'm really not happy with that solution.

The container itself will be a pure component (although I can change that if I absolutely need to and I imagine it to look something like this:

```
const Container = props => <section><some-variable store={store} name={props.name} foo={props.foo}></some-variable></section>
```

Although I'm unsure how to replace the `some-variable` part with an actual component.

Edit: In an attempt to clear up my question. I've written out a real-world example of the sort of thing I expected to do to make this work (but it doesn't work, I think I'm close though and the error below is probably the result of a dumb mistake):

```
import React, { cloneElement } from 'react'

import Perception from '../FormChildPerception'
import PlannedStatus from '../FormChildPlannedStatus'
import Adjudication from '../FormChildAdjudication'

import './styles.scss'

const componentRegistry = [
  {
    name: 'perception',
    element: Perception
  },
  {
    name: 'planned-status',
    element: PlannedStatus
  },
  {
    name: 'adjudication',
    element: Adjudication
  }
]

const Form = props => {
  const component = componentRegistry.find(component => component.name === props.child)

  return (
    <section className="form-container">
      {
        cloneElement(component.element, {
          store: props.store,
          onStoreUpdate: props.onStoreUpdate,
          callbackFunction: props.callbackFunction
        })
      }
    </section>
  )
}
export default Form
```

This produces the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: Honestly, your question is too difficult to understand. Are `ChildOne`, `ChildTwo`, `ChildThree` are some component classes are different.

Comment: So `ChildOne`, `ChildTwo` and `ChildThree` are all different components which can slot into the parent, however, each one has the exact same props.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of Component classes and map

```js
   const Container = ({component: Comp, store, name }) => (
   <section>
     <Comp store={store} name={name}></some-variable>
   </section>
);

const data = [
  [ChildOne, 'child-one'], [ChildTwo, 'child-two'], [ChildThree, 'child-three']
];

{data.map(([Comp, name]) => <Container component={Comp} name={name} store={store} />)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some helper to resolve what component you need to use. For example -

```
const components = new Map([
    ["first-child", FirstChildComponent],
    ["second-child", SecondChildComponent],
    ...etc.
]);
const getNecessaryComponent = (componentName = "some default value") => {
    return components.get(componentName);
});
```

And in your container you can use this function for resolving what component you need to use -

```
const Container = props => {
    const Component = getNecessaryComponent(props.child);
    return (
        <section>
             <Component 
                 store={store}
                 name={props.name}
                 foo={props.foo}
             ></Component>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, the answer was to change the `componentRegistry` to the following:

```
const componentRegistry = [
  {
    name: 'perception',
    element: <Perception />
  },
  {
    name: 'planned-status',
    element: <PlannedStatus />
  },
  {
    name: 'adjudication',
    element: <Adjudication />
  }
]
```